# In Laravel, How to get data from 2 tables data which are not existing in both tables

Tags: laravel

[image]

### table 1

### | ID | val1 |

### | 1  |  a   |

### | 2  |  b   |

### | 3  |  c   |

### table 2

### | ID | val1 |

### | 1  |  a   |

### | 2  |  b   |

I need to get the table1 data, which is not on table 2

```
$users_without_info = DB::table('users')->rightJoin('user_infos', 'users.email', '=', 'user_infos.email')
->select('users.*')
->latest()
->get();
```

I tried this command, doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

use inner join

```
$users_without_info = DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_infos', 'users.email', '!=', 'user_infos.email')
        ->select('users.*')
        ->latest()
        ->get();
```

if you have models then use relationships with the foreign key then in user model add relation

```
public function userInfo(){

   return $this->hasOne(UserInfo::class);
}
```

and the query will be

```
$users_without_info=\App\Models\User::doesntHave('userInfo')->get();
```

if you don't have foreign key and want to use email as unique identifier then

```
public function userInfo(){

 return $this->hasOne(UserInfo::class,'email','email');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Here is the solution,

- The issue is in the join statement.
- You can try this way to get the table-1(*users*) data, which is not on table-2(*user_infos*),

> ```
> $users_without_info = DB::table('users')
>   ->leftJoin('user_infos', 'users.email', '=', 'user_infos.email')
>   ->whereNull('user_infos.email')
>   ->get();
> ```

*Hope you will fix it..*